# Show metrics on Travis-CI

Tags: travis-ci

Is is possible to configure Travis-CI t show metrics like SonarQube provides (http://nemo.sonarqube.org/) like

- % duplicate lines
- % code coverage
- % rules appliance
- % documented methods
- etc

and see it graphically?

Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=travis-ci+code+coverage

Comment: I know I can see code coverage, but I can't see the others...

Answer (score 0):

I did not come across such setting. For Travis CI it would mean running scanners, which are highly dependent on the used by the project technologies.

However http://container-solutions.com/moved-ci-jenkins-travis/ explains how you can get SonarQube commenting code **changes** in GitHub pull requests.